# Can not click link on google map page with htmlunit

Tags: java, eclipse, google-maps, servlets, htmlunit

Currently, i'm trying to control google map JP with htmlunit.
Here's [a link](https://maps.google.co.jp/) of google map JP.
In my browser,there is a menu at left side(old style view), and it shows city name just after i click on prefecture name.I want to do same action by using htmlunit but nothing changes.
Please give me some idea and help me(using servlet atm).

```
package com.example.part1;

import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController;


@WebServlet(“/test")

public class test extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    public test() {

        super();

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

response.setContentType("text/html; charset=Windows-31J");
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME, "198.23.143.27", 5555);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
        webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://maps.google.co.jp/");        

        List<HtmlAnchor> links = (List<HtmlAnchor>) page1.getByXPath("//a[@href='javascript:void(0)']");


        //click 北海道
        links.get(12).click();

        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
        response.getWriter().write(page1.getWebResponse().getContentAsString());

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Here's [a image file for explanation](http://uploda.cc/img/img530d6889bdccf.jpg)!

Any advice are welcome.
Thanks in Advance.

**Edit**
Still looking for solution

Comment: r u sure that element 12 in the list in the appropriate anchor u want to click ??

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Yes.i’m pretty much sure element 12 is correct.It says “北海道",with System.out.println(links.get(12).asText()).If you have any idea, please help me...

Answer (score 0):

When you click the `anchor`,save the result in the HtmlPage as below :

```
page1  = links.get(12).click();
```

Edit.Added class to click on the button, also added screenshot of page that i receive after click

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.List;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
        webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://maps.google.co.jp/");        

        List<HtmlAnchor> links = (List<HtmlAnchor>) page.getByXPath("//a[@href='javascript:void(0)']");

        page = links.get(12).click();

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("d:\\test.html"); //To write page in file
        writer.write(page.asXml());
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @user3348619 i have tested on my system and it works fine by making said change in the code.U can also use asXml method to view the page

Comment: Hi Niks. I have tried “page1 = links.get(12).click();” and "page1.asXml()”.But it shows completely same with before clicking.If its possible, can you paste code you tested?[My test result is Here](http://uploda.cc/img/img530f94357a547.jpg) thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3348619 i have added my code and paste the image that received after click.

Comment: Sry, prob my explanation was not so good. well...Usually Google JP shows city name after clicking prefecture name. After clicking prefecture name, its name disappear and alternatively shows its city name , or city name list. Take a look at left side of image. And then, with our code, it still shows prefecture name, there are no city name and nothing changes compared with non-clicking. Take a look at right side of image.[Click Here for Image](http://uploda.cc/img/img5310b31cac407.jpg).Thanks.